# How to get refreshToken on react-native-auth0

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, auth0, react-native-auth0

i'm using react-native-auth0 to handle my SSO.
Login works, but my refresh token is null. Why?

This is the code:

```
import {useAuth0} from 'react-native-auth0';

export const LoginScreen = () => {
  const {authorize, error} = useAuth0();

  const onPressLogin = async () => {
    const credentials = await authorize();
  };

  return ....;
};

   "react-native-auth0": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
```

In this case, when i call `authorize`, open correctly auth0 modal, login succesfully with email and password, and the credentials response is:

```
 {
    "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCI........Qjf8JLAzF-wc1oqw",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "expiresAt": 1700665033,
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbm.......RxDDBy54rT9KGlg",
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "refreshToken": null
}
```

The configuration of auth0 are:
[image]

[image]

How can I get the refresh token and perform the refresh operation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `offline_access` to scope in [authorize](https://auth0.github.io/react-native-auth0/interfaces/Types.Auth0ContextInterface.html#authorize) request and enable offline access from the settings.

> The refresh_token will only be present in the response if you included the offline_access scope and enabled Allow Offline Access for your API in the Dashboard.

See [Add Login Using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/add-login-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce)  for details.

Comment: Thanks!

I use      
const credentials = await authorize({
     scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
 });

And now when i call getCredentials() will refresh my accessToken